# Google API backend error - if we use Google Cloud Client Library, would we see less Backend Errors?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

When we use Google Apps Script to call the Google/YouTube API (such as YouTube API, YouTube Content ID API etc), 3 legged oAuth authentication approach, sometimes we got the message "backend error". If we tried again, the same call would be successful. The backend error rate sometimes is pretty high.

We also used (we also could use) Google Cloud Client Library and service account to call Google/YouTube API, 2 legged oAuth authentication approach to make the same API call.

Due to Google encourages us to use newer Cloud Client Library if we can ,instead of the older API library, I am wondering will the backend error rate going down if we use the Google cloud client library calling the Google API instead.

Or backend error is purely on Google Backend, it does not matter which library we use to call the API?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the API and library, there *may* be automatic retry for idempotent calls, which would make it *look* more reliable (just with higher latency in some cases). But it's not like there's any magic password that the libraries use to make the backends more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud's Client Libraries can give you some performance benefits by using gRPC. This is because gRPC-enabled API clients use protocol buffers and gRPC over HTTP2 to talk to the RPC interface.

Protocol buffers are smaller and faster than using JSON over HTTP to the REST interface. So, in a way, they're better for everyone and can provide lots of benefits in terms of throughput and CPU usage.
But, if there's a fail after the backend's RPC interface, then there is no difference.

Also note that they could provide an exponential backoff strategy to handle errors and retries.